# Issues with collision detection is JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically what I'm attempting to do is create a little platforming game without the use of tiles, so I must do a lot by hand. I'm perfectly fine doing that minus collision detection which has caused me problems in the past. The problem currently is that certain platform objects (you'll see) refuse to work properly while others have no issues.

I had most of this working before-hand, and it just now has started messing up big time, only after I added friction and gravity.

```
handle_all_collisions: function(player) {
    if (player.position.x < 0) {
        player.position.x = 0;
    } else if (player.position.x + player.bounds.x > canvas.width) {
        player.position.x = canvas.width - player.bounds.x;
    }

    if (player.position.y < 0) {
        player.position.y = 0;
    } else if (player.position.y + player.bounds.y > canvas.height) {
        global.world.ground = true;
        player.position.y = canvas.height - player.bounds.y;
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < positions.length; i++) {
            if (collisions.is_colliding(player, obstacles[i])) {
                global.world.ground = true;
            } else {
                global.world.ground = false;
            }
        }
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < positions.length; i++) {
        if (collisions.is_colliding(player, obstacles[i])) {
            collisions.resolve_collision(player, obstacles[i]);
        } else {
            player.collided.up = false;
            player.collided.down = false;
            player.collided.left = false;
            player.collided.right = false;
        }
    }
}
```

This handles all the collisions so that I can use certain information later. You'll notice I have a `global.world.ground = true/false` in there, which is used to change the player's y position. This wouldn't be a problem if at certain times it's not setting to true to allow jumping. I've been doing this on my [repl.it](https://repl.it/@cervine/basic-platformer) which will showcase it better. Another problem is when you walk off the left platform (the troublemaker) you end up disappearing into the floor, which I think is caused by the faulty detection.

My end goal is to get collision detection fixed to near perfect as it can get without predicting where I'm going to be in the next few frames. I don't really want to change my Object creation technique as I wish to keep it as short as I can. Thank you for taking the time to read over this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your biggest problem is this condition:

```
for (var i = 0; i < positions.length; i++) {
    if (collisions.is_colliding(player, obstacles[i])) {
        global.world.ground = true;
    } else {
        global.world.ground = false;
    }
}
```

This basically just tests if the player is colliding with *the last* obstacle, because `global.world.ground` is overwritten in every iteration. You should move `global.world.ground = false;` to the top of the function, because you want to test if the player is colliding with *any* obstacle.

Your platforms behave differently because the game only recognizes the right platform (the one you added last) as a platform to stand on. If you jump on the left platform, it just pushes you out of it using the function `resolve_collision` later in the function `handle_all_collisions`.

The second thing you missed is resetting the player's velocity when they collide with something. In the function `resolve_collision` you should set `player.velocity.x = 0` whenever there was a collision on the x-axis and `player.velocity.y = 0` if the collision was on the y axis. So when you stand on the left platform you do get pushed out of it upwards, but you velocity does not get reset, so in the background the player accumulates all the gravitational acceleration and gets flung down through the platform after a while because the collision detection can't handle those speeds.

When you stand on the ground obstacle (which is not the last obstacle), it's almost the same thing. It does not get recognized as the ground either, but because of the player's increasing speed they get registered as standing on the real bottom of the canvas after a short while. That's why you could not jump for a second or two after landing on the ground obstacle.

I fixed these things in this copy of your repl: https://repl.it/repls/AfraidNaiveQuote

The are still some issues left, but I'm running out of time and I think you might be able to fix them yourself. The player is interpreted to be on the ground when they are colliding with something to the left for example. So they can get stuck to walls.

Comment: Thank you for explaining it all to me, I never really thought about it when creating it, I was just assuming that it was some flaw elsewhere. I was meaning to reset the y-velocity and x-velocity, but I suppose I completely forgot about it when trying to fix some other issues. I did notice times where I got stuck on the sides of the platforms, and I was thinking about using it as a "feature" later on in the development, hence why there's the ```player.collided.up = false;``` and a few other directions for that reason. It's amazing how things so simple can be the hardest.